# Android app stops when navigating

Tags: android, android-intent, navigation

I am new to android, my app fails or stops working when I click the navigate button which should direct me to another activity. This is my code to navigate to the next activity.

```
public void checkout(View view) {
      Intent intent = new Intent(this, SelectedItemsControl.class);
      startActivity(intent);
}
```

My SelectedItemsControl.class code:

```
public class SelectedItemsControl extends AppCompatActivity {

    ListView lv2 ;
    ArrayList<String> CheckoutList ;
    ArrayAdapter adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.selecteditems);

lv2 =  (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listviewtwo);
        CheckoutList = new ArrayList<>();
        adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2,CheckoutList);
lv2.setAdapter(adapter);

    }
}
```

Comment: your class name having space? ,Selected Items Control. class

Comment: ,Selected Items Control. class is declared in manifest?

Comment: post your code and error

Comment: The class name is "SelectedItemsControl",  the code shown here was automatically formatted while posting but in the code I use there are no spaces in the class name .

Comment: make sure you have declared your activity at manifest, post your stackTrace if still the issue came

Comment: I will post it in parts @zaki, they restrict me from posting the whole thing as  it is too long

Comment: Register SelectedItemsControl in manifest. Also post your SelectedItemsControl class code and its layout file

Comment: @AnkushBist are you referring to the android manifest file ?

Comment: @Evan yes just making sure that you have declared your activity at manifest or not. Sometime we forgot to mention it.

Comment: Looks like either you haven't register activity in manifest or there is exception in SelectedItemsControl. Also , selectedItemsControl  class should extend from any Activity class

Comment: @Pehlaj  public class SelectedItemsControl extends AppCompatActivity{} is this okay ?

Comment: Yes. There might be some exception in class. Can you please post your SelectedItemsControl class in question section?

Comment: yes this is ok @Evan. Share your code so we can give you correct answer

Comment: please try to comment the code in SelectedItemsControl.class. and just set single Textview in selecteditems.xml. you got the error if there is an error in Activity

Comment: @Evan you understand what I am asking to do?

Comment: yes i do , and it is working fine now . I need help with another issue now  lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int Position, long id) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, " You Selected  "+((TextView) view).getText() , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        });

Comment: @ZakiPathan here i am getting the selected item and displaying it, can you help me get it and populate another list view ?

Comment: where you have to display? you have to display in different listview from first listview?

Comment: yes @ZakiPathan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check manifest. Your activity is declared or not there

```
<activity android:name=".SelectedItemsControl" />
```

hope it helps you. If you have some different problem please ask me will help you, If this doesn't help try second option

```
public void checkout(View view){
    Intent intent = new Intent(FirstActivity.this, SecondActivity.class); 
    startActivity(intent); }
```

try to comment code in your second Activity. It helps if you have any error in second activity.

```
public class SelectedItemsControl extends AppCompatActivity {

    ListView lv2 ;
    ArrayList<String> CheckoutList ;
    ArrayAdapter adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.selecteditems);

/*lv2 =  (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listviewtwo);
        CheckoutList = new ArrayList<>();
        adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2,CheckoutList);
lv2.setAdapter(adapter);*/

    }
}
```

Comment: alright thanks, I tried using the second activity's object to populate the list view in the first class so that it is filled instead of passing it, is that correct practice ?

Comment: show me your code how you set listview adapter in second Activity while clicking on first activity listview item?

Answer (score 1):

Your code Should look like

```
public void checkout(View view){
    Intent intent = new Intent(FirstActivity.this, SecondActivity.class); // no space in class name
    startActivity(intent); }//no space between Start and Activity.
```

Comment: Also, check that your SelectedItemsControl is existing Activity and register in manifest as well. by,
<activity android:name=".SelectedItemsControl" />

Comment: also make sure that, "checkout" method is called on button click listener.

Comment: <Button
        android:text="Button"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:onClick="checkout"
        /> this is what i used , i thought i can use the "onClick" call from the xml instead of the button listener, is this correct ?

Comment: @Upsana Thank you for your help